# Picking a hymn with a minimum numbers of clicks from main menu

Tags: mobile, navigation, design-patterns, android

I am building an android app (hymn book). Users need to pick a particular hymn with a minimum number of clicks from the main menu.

The problem is that the hymns are around 800+ and will keep increasing.

I am considering the faceted navigation list pattern where the user can type either the hymn number or part of the words in the hymn's title and the app will show matching hymns.

Is this the best pattern available for such use-case, do you have effective solution to solve this problem? Can you suggest any interaction patterns that will work?

Thanks

Comment: [UX Myth #2: All pages should be accessible in 3 clicks](http://uxmyths.com/post/654026581/myth-all-pages-should-be-accessible-in-3-clicks)

Comment: @JonW. I read the article you linked to. Great article but it isn't really relevant in this case. The user **must** open the hymn within a narrow time-space( i.e. before the others start singing the hymn). So, if i can beat the three-click rule, then awesome.

Comment: In that case your question should state that it is a speed issue, not a click one. For instance I could do a 3-clicks system that could take 5 minutes to use! (I'd be a bad UX designer if I did that, but still...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That pattern is a good start, both accessing a hymn by number or via a few words from its title or any of its verses.  I would also suggest that include a "favorites list" and maybe something to facilitate pre-service preparation.  By that, I mean that prior to a service beginning, a user could enter all of the hymns for the up coming service, then operate from a simple list thereafter.

If you are trying to address the needs of ministers/service-organizers, you might want to add in a calendar so that hymn selections can be entered for multiple services across multiple days or weeks.

If you are trying to address the needs of a hymnest, you might want to have the user interface warn them when they choose the same pre or post service hymn for multiple ajacent services.

Comment: Since, the app will be mainly for users, i will implement the favourites list idea. I will go a long way in alleviating the hymn search issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I love your idea, and it is used in other examples as well. (The LDS has a Gospel Library app, with a digital hymn book, that functions in a similar fashion.) But I have a few ideas to add, if they sound decent.

This first idea is related to Google's Instant Results. Pretend I'm looking for hymn... #314, let's go with that. What if you made it so when I write 3, it lists hymns 3, 30-39, and 300-399? Then, I write 31, so it lists 31, and 310-319. I don't know what it's called, but that's one idea. It lists everything that starts with what was written. In this case, if I wanted 314, I'd write 3, 1, and see the link to 314. 3 clicks, done.

Another idea is to count how many times each hymn file was opened this month, and delete counts more than a month old. (Change this as applicable. How often should it be used?) Then, on the main page, have a "sort by commonly used" or "sort by popular" or whatever button. List the ones with highest count first, and if there's a tie, fallback to numerical.

Also, categories are a MUST with huge indexes, especially if exploration is involved. Why not provide filters based on topic?

Comment: Thanks. The Google's Instant Results process you described is the same as faceted navigation list pattern. But i like the idea of keeping tabs of opened hymns and ranking accordingly